# C++ GetModuleBase on linux

Tags: c++, linux, process, module

So recently I was trying to work with a process, to read/write memory from/to the process.
I've written a little wrapper class for ptrace, and I'm using that at the moment.

However the process uses multiple shared objects, which I need the offset of, in order to calculate the address.

So let's say on the windows version of my process, the address is **base.dll+0xFF00**, so on linux I'm expecting it to be **base.so+0xFF00**, I've found a nice alternative to cheat engine called scanmem, in combination with gameconqueror.

However, I am not able to get the base address of the base.so, I've found [this](http://pastebin.com/NiSnzfDj) code for windows systems, however that does not work on linux systems.

So all over this is what I'm looking for:
**A function that gets the base address of a module within a process, by it's name, like: getModuleBase(pid,"base.so");**

Is this even possible, or am I looking into something that won't even work anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you could use the linux specific (actually GNU libc specific) [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) function, assuming you know the address of some function symbol inside it.

Otherwise, you could read *sequentially* and parse the `/proc/self/maps`  file from inside your program (or `/proc/1234/maps`  for the process of pid 1234). [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) is Linux specific, and reading files in `/proc/`  is quick (no disk IO involved since `/proc/`  is implemented inside the kernel without physical I/O). Try in a terminal

```
cat /proc/self/maps
```

it will show you the memory map of the process executing that `cat`  command

I am not sure that the idea of a well-defined and unique *base address* of a dynamically loaded (`dlopen`-ed) plugin is meaningful. Shared objects ELF files (i.e. `plugin.so` files) generally have several segments. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24807872/841108) (and think about [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) ...)